# DAO query does not work with MIN MAX functions

Tags: android, sql, dao, android-room, android-jetpack

I have designed a room db for my android app. All of my DAO interface methods are working except when I have a min/max functions in a query.

Here is mock of entity class:

```
@Entity
public class Data {

    @PrimaryKey
    @NonNull
    private String timestamp;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "item_key")
    private int itemKey;

    ...Other stuff...
}
```

and here is a class to have only the needed parts:

```
public class HeaderData {
    private int item_key;
    private String timestamp;

    public HeaderData(int item_key, String timestamp) {
        this.item_key = item_key;
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }
}
```

and here is DAO interface:

```
@Dao
public interface LocationDao {

    @Insert
    void insertSingleRecord(Data data);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM Data")
    List<LocationData> getEverything();

    @Query("SELECT * FROM Data WHERE item_key = :itemKey")
    List<Data> getDbData(int itemKey);

    // I dont know why this query is not working!
    @Query("SELECT item_key, MIN(timestamp) FROM LocationData GROUP BY item_key")
    List<HeaderData> getHeaderData();
}
```

In the last query `getHeaderData()` the `MIN` function seems not working and I get a list of header data with correct `item_key`s but all the `timestamp`s are `null` . Does anybody knows the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

THe problem is that your return pojo is not exactly what you're asking from the database:

```
// I dont know why this query is not working!
    @Query("SELECT item_key, MIN(timestamp) FROM LocationData GROUP BY item_key")
    List<HeaderData> getHeaderData();
```

HeaderData does have an item_key, but MIN(timestamp) is not the same as timestamp, it's another column. That's why timestamp is comming as null. What you can do is define your pojo like this:

```
public class HeaderData {
    private int item_key;
    private String minTimestamp;


    public HeaderData(int item_key, String minTimestamp) {
        this.item_key = item_key;
        this.minTimestamp = minTimestamp;
    }
}
```

And redefine your query as such:

```
    @Query("SELECT item_key, MIN(timestamp) as minTimestamp  FROM LocationData GROUP BY item_key")
    List<HeaderData> getHeaderData();
```

Comment: Any idea how to get just the MIN or MAX value? For some reason, I always get 0 for it, as the returned type of the function should be "int" .